# Issue in Integrating metamask to chrome browser in mobile

Tags: metamask, wallets, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I am trying to create an DeFi app by integrating the MetaMask wallet.

**Desktop**

The DeFi app works fine with the MetaMask integration

**Mobile**

I have my MetaMask setup in my Android mobile. When I tried the same DeFi App in my Android mobile, it is not connecting with the MetaMask at my mobile.
*I have not tried in iOS*

I am not sure whether I am missing anything in the mobile side. Please assist me in integrating MetaMask with mobile chrome browser.